# PDO fetch me a fake result

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm working on a function that compare two price.

I have a table called 'PRODUCT' that has 3 column: ID, REFERENCE, PRICE.

I get a price from a FORM that i will compare with the column PRICE. If the number that i get with the form, is different by PRICE from the table, i want get the REFERENCE. So i work in this way:

```
$pdo = new PDO ("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);

    $sql = "SELECT count(1) as NB
    FROM ww_ps_product
    WHERE reference = :reference AND SUBSTR(wholesale_price , 1, INSTR(wholesale_price ,'.')+2)  != :price" ;

    $stmt =  $pdo->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindValue(':reference', **$referenza**, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':price', **$prezzoAggiornato**);

    $stmt->execute();

    $product = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

The value that i get from the form :  $referenza is **FIN 260482300000** and the $prezzoAggiornato is **6.90** . Normalli, in my $product, i should have **0** but i get **1**.

This data are store in DB with the same values:

[image]

When i go to compare with my function, i get **NB = 1** but  that's is impossible. If i check with the same values in phpMyAdmin i get **NB = 0**.

There is something wrong in my code?

Comment: Sounds likely you've got a rounding / floating point handling error, and the price in PHP isn't _exactly_ 6.90

Comment: As a general tip, saying something is "impossible" or "fake" is rarely a productive way of looking at the problem. Computers are **extremely** logical, so bugs generally turn out to be the program doing *exactly what you asked*, just not what you *intended* to ask. So you have to look for places where there is room for ambiguity, and floating point numbers are one of those places.

Comment: I added this in my where for avoid this error :  SUBSTR(`wholesale_price` , 1, INSTR(`wholesale_price` ,'.')+2) 

And in phpmyadmin when i execute this query, that s work fine

Comment: Right, but what about the _other side_ of the `!=`? What is the precise value of `$prezzoAggiornato`, to the accuracy that MySQL sees it?

Comment: Try `echo "$sql -$prezzoAggiornato";` to see what you get. If you don't want to echo it, find a way to log it.

Comment: @IMSoP $prezzoAggiornato = 6.90. Si, i compare 6.90 <> 6.90